# Mock 'element' in jest tests

Tags: jestjs, detox

I have a helper which I use for Detox tests which hold abstractions of most commonly occurring actions. Like this.

```js
/**
 * Looks for a search input and inputs the query
 */
export const inputSearchQuery = async ({ query = '', placeholderText = '' }) => {
  if (placeholderText) {
    // look for search input
    await expect(element(by.id(TestID.SEARCH_INPUT).withDescendant(by.text(placeholderText)))).toBeVisible();

    // tap search input
    await element(by.id(TestID.SEARCH_INPUT).withDescendant(by.text(placeholderText))).tap();

    // type in query
    await element(by.id(TestID.SEARCH_INPUT).withDescendant(by.text(placeholderText))).typeText(query);
  } else {
    // look for search input
    await expect(element(by.id(TestID.SEARCH_INPUT))).toBeVisible();

    // tap search input
    await element(by.id(TestID.SEARCH_INPUT)).tap();

    // type in query
    await element(by.id(TestID.SEARCH_INPUT)).typeText(query);
  }
};
```

I want this layer of abstraction to be tested with Jest. So I did the following,

```js
describe('e2e helper', () => {
  describe('inputSearchQuery()', () => {
    test('should check whether the search input is visible', async () => {
      const mockToBeVisible = jest.fn();

      await inputSearchQuery({});

      expect(mockToBeVisible).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
});
```

And obviously got the error,

> ReferenceError: element is not defined

I understand that `element` comes from the environment. How do I configure my Jest setup...

```
"jest": {
        "preset": "react-native",
        "snapshotSerializers": [
          "./node_modules/enzyme-to-json/serializer"
        ],
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
          "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-navigation)"
        ],
        "moduleNameMapper": {
          "package.json": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/package.json"
        },
        "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
          "/e2e/"
        ],
        // I'm guessing something like this but doesn't work out of the box
        "testEnvironment": "detox"
      },
```

...to address this?

Comment: Are you trying to unit test your e2e tests?

Comment: Yes. Thought it might be faster to do that if I'm to go through e2e tests written by several juniors.